# CakePHP read() not retrieving belongsTo bindings

Tags: php, cakephp, belongs-to, findall

I have a model called `Voicenote` with has a `belongsTo` relationship with `Fonyker` and `ActivitySource`. When I do the following:

```
function admin_index(){

        $this->layout = 'admin';
        $this->Voicenote->recursive = 2;

        $fields = array(
            'Voicenote.id',
            'Voicenote.title',
            'Voicenote.created',
            'Voicenote.duration',
            'Voicenote.public',
        );

        $this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => $fields,
            'limit' => 20,
            'order' => array('id' => 'ASC')
        );

        $result = $this->paginate('Voicenote');
        pr($result);
        $this->set('result', $result);
    }
```

The resulting array comes without `Fonyker` and `ActivitySource`, any ideas on what might be happening?

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [Voicenote] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => CFRFA5KBLPJZP79B2PG8XH8DFSMB8G
                    [created] => 2011-03-09 00:00:00
                    [duration] => 23868
                    [public] => 0
                )

            [Fonyker] => Array
                (
                )

            [ActivitySource] => Array
                (
                )
```

Also when I try using `unbindModel()` and unbind everything but `Fonyker` and `ActivitySource` they don't even show up as empty arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `recursive = 2` and seeing empty `Fonyker` and `ActivitySource` arrays you're definitely querying those models, but your restrictive `'fields'` means you're only going to get the fields you've listed.

You need to add the fields you need from `Fonyker` and `ActivitySource` into your fields array.

Comment: How do I add them? just Fonyker.field ? And I've tried using the other recursive types and also binding and unbinding the models and it still won't retrive any of the data fromt the tables

Comment: If I remove the recursive it will retrieve the main table with all it's relations EXCEPT the Fonyker and ActivitySource tables

Comment: @8vius Just add "'Fonyker.field'," to the end of you $fields array, e.g. just after "'Voicenote.public'," (without double quotes of course).

Comment: It says it's an unknown column in the SQL error when I add the fields external to Voicenote

Comment: @8vius can you change the 'order' entry to be 'Voicenote.id' rather than 'id', this might be your problem as id is going to be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to CakePHP myself, but I think you have to have to define `Fonyker` and `ActivitySource` models as well? For example, put them in a `hasOne` or `hasMany` relationship.

Edit: Also, your `$fields` variable -- you don't seem to be selecting any values from `Fonyker` or `ActivitySource`.

Comment: They are in the moded as belongsTo and it doesn't matter if I'm not selecting any specific fields from them, it'll just retrive the entire data, i don't show it in the code snippet but it does retrieve the data from the other tables, just not the 2 i want